# Uninstall postgresql on MacOs Lion Mountain

Tags: macos, postgresql

I'm completely new with MacOS X and I'm not underestanding where my system postgresql 9.1.5 is installed. I want to upgrade to 9.2 but I would like to uninstall this default installation before.

When I type in the terminal

```
$> psql --version
```

The result is:

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.1.5
```

but I can not find this installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MacOS X does not come with PostgreSQL installed as a server (unless you have OS X Server Edition).

Only the **client-side** PostgreSQL commands and the `libpq` library ship with the system. These include the `psql` command that resides is `/usr/bin` along with other commands such as `pg_dump`, `pg_restore`, `createdb`... You don't have to remove them, and if you did, it's not clear anyway what would prevent the next maintenance update of the OS to put them back.

So if you didn't previously install PostgreSQL yourself on this system, going to 9.2 is not an upgrade, it's a fresh install.

There are a number of providers of [PostgreSQL packages for Mac OS X](http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/): `postgres.app`, `homebrew`, `fink`, `macports`...
These packages provide both a server and the client tools with the same version than the server, they have distinct installation paths, and they don't overwrite anything in `/usr/bin`. Once installed, you want to use the commands from the package preferrably to the ones in `/usr/bin`, which means technically putting them first in your `PATH`. Each package I've seen comes with a mention on how to do that in its installation instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to remove the version Apple ships.

I have been using MacPorts to run various custom builds of PostgreSQL on OSX. It takes a little effort to make it "just work" (PATH and PG environment variables) but I never had to remove Apple's copy of Postgres.

I also keep a VM (VirtualBox) of a pretty minimal Debian install with Postgres running. I can do all my testing against the VM with a change of PG variables or JDBC URL. It's not as performant as running on the host but it is really clean for development.